# Identifying the cause of a InnoDB deadlock

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I've managed to solve many deadlocks in my time, and they've usually involved contrary `ORDER BY` clauses but this one has me stumped:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2017-09-04 03:06:37 0x7fe24c089700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 58577744, ACTIVE 1 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 414 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1921752, OS thread handle 140609486370560, query id 50687761 localhost spikeatschool updating
UPDATE `image_gallery_categories` SET `position` = (`image_gallery_categories`.`position` + 1), `updated_at` = '2017-09-04 03:06:36.313021' WHERE `image_gallery_categories`.`image_gallery_id` = 997 AND `image_gallery_categories`.`startup` = 1
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 88146 page no 6 n bits 320 index PRIMARY of table `94e842b4c723600d`.`image_gallery_categories` trx id 58577744 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 99 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 32
0: len 4; hex 8000030a; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000037dd321; asc    } !;;
2: len 7; hex 60000003f52351; asc `    #Q;;
3: len 7; hex 4b69776963616e; asc Kiwican;;
4: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
5: len 4; hex 8000033e; asc    >;;
6: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
7: len 5; hex 999d38024b; asc   8 K;;
8: len 5; hex 999d8831a4; asc    1 ;;
9: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 58577697, ACTIVE 23 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
26 lock struct(s), heap size 3520, 118 row lock(s), undo log entries 541
MySQL thread id 1923177, OS thread handle 140609914967808, query id 50687925 localhost spikeatschool updating
UPDATE `image_gallery_categories` SET `image_gallery_categories`.`updated_at` = '2017-09-04 03:06:37' WHERE `image_gallery_categories`.`id` = 771
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 88146 page no 6 n bits 320 index PRIMARY of table `94e842b4c723600d`.`image_gallery_categories` trx id 58577697 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 99 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 32
0: len 4; hex 8000030a; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000037dd321; asc    } !;;
2: len 7; hex 60000003f52351; asc `    #Q;;
3: len 7; hex 4b69776963616e; asc Kiwican;;
4: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
5: len 4; hex 8000033e; asc    >;;
6: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
7: len 5; hex 999d38024b; asc   8 K;;
8: len 5; hex 999d8831a4; asc    1 ;;
9: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;

Record lock, heap no 104 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 32
0: len 4; hex 80000311; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000037dd321; asc    } !;;
2: len 7; hex 60000003f519b8; asc `      ;;
3: len 23; hex 4e67c4812050c5ab72c4816b617520c481204dc4817569; asc Ng   P  r  kau    M  ui;;
4: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
5: len 4; hex 8000033e; asc    >;;
6: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
7: len 5; hex 999d3802f8; asc   8  ;;
8: len 5; hex 999d8831a3; asc    1 ;;
9: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 88146 page no 6 n bits 320 index PRIMARY of table `94e842b4c723600d`.`image_gallery_categories` trx id 58577697 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 93 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 80000303; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000002d1715c; asc     q\;;
2: len 7; hex 73000003df1872; asc s     r;;
3: len 14; hex 4d616e7572657761204d61726165; asc Manurewa Marae;;
4: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
5: len 4; hex 8000033e; asc    >;;
6: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
7: len 5; hex 999d380226; asc   8 &;;
8: len 5; hex 999d3802f9; asc   8  ;;
9: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Is it because of the differing `WHERE` clauses? How would I go about mitigating this? The SQL is generated by Ruby on Rails so I don't have much control over it.

**UPDATE**
The only other query before the first transactions query is:

```
SELECT `image_gallery_category_images`.* FROM `image_gallery_category_images` WHERE `image_gallery_category_images`.`image_gallery_category_id` = 734  ORDER BY `image_gallery_category_images`.`position` ASC
```

There doesn't appear to be a transaction begun as `COMMIT` is on the line above.

The other transaction has this as the only other relevant query:

```
SELECT  `image_gallery_categories`.* FROM `image_gallery_categories` WHERE `image_gallery_categories`.`id` = 771 LIMIT 1
```

The actual logs for each of these requests are huge as they're doing a lot so it's hard to piece it all together. In this case, Rails is unnecessarily touching parent table records that are eventually deleted anyway. Plenty to look into and I think I have some clues as to how to avoid this going forward.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE image_gallery_categories` - we need to see your indexes, datatypes, etc.  Is id=771 one of the rows with gallery_id=997?  And what other SQL statements were between the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`?

Comment: Trx 2 is waiting for the lock on `0: len 4; hex 80000303; asc     ;;` => id 771.  Trx 2 holds locks on other rows, so there are almost certainly multiple other queries that have been run in that single transaction.  Presumably Trx 1 holds this lock, even though it isn't mentioned.

Comment: Ah I see, so there's more to the story. I'll try to pull up the logs.